# getting next page of my wordpress site feeds - wordpress site

Tags: android, wordpress, rss

I have a wordpress site and I want to create an android application for that.
I want to get my site posts via rss of wordpress but wordpress feeds just return last 10 posts of all category for example with this URL:

mysite.com/feed

an I want to load continues of posts to load in application and get feeds with category name or ID

**what URL or plugin  I had to use for this?**

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think the rss feed is not proper way for developing an application of site you should create the web services for developing applications.

Comment: thank you but this is the second solution for me ;)